# Exception in thread "HikariPool-3 connection closer"

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, mysql-connector, hikaricp

I have a projet in `Spring Boot 2.1.2` and `Hibernate 5.4.1`. I chose `HikariCP 3.3.1` as a pool manager for my MySQL database connected with `MySQL Connector 8.0.15`

Everything seems working fine, but some exceptions begin to appear in logs after some times :

```
Exception in thread "HikariPool-4 connection closer" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/cj/log/ProfilerEventHandlerFactory
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:1765)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionImpl.java:720)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.quietlyCloseConnection(PoolBase.java:138)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.lambda$closeConnection$1(HikariPool.java:447)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I don't know what this means, thus how to get rid of these messages. Could it be related to the fact that my controllers can't connect to the database after some times ?

Here is a part of my hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
    <!--HikariCP settings-->
    <!--Maximum waiting time for a connection from the pool-->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.connectionTimeout">20000</property>
    <!--Minimum number of ideal connections in the pool-->
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle">10</property>
    <!--Maximum number of actual connection in the pool-->
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize">100</property>
    <!--Maximum time that a connection is allowed to sit ideal in the pool-->
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout">300000</property>
    <!--Cache-->
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.cachePrepStmts">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize">500</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">2048</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.useServerPrepStmts">true</property>


    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8mb4</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect.storage_engine">innodb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">false</property>
    <property name="use_sql_comments">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory</property>
    <property name="jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes">true</property>
```

I work with gradle, here are my maven dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.1.Final'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:5.4.1.Final'
    implementation 'com.zaxxer:HikariCP:3.3.1'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.15'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.9.8'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.9.8'
    implementation 'org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:7.0.0.CR1'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.7.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:1.20'

    implementation 'com.wildbit.java:postmark:1.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You exception message is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/cj/log/ProfilerEventHandlerFactory

It look's like something wrong with your mysql driver.

could you show your pom.xml?
It could be help to solve the problem.

Comment: Maven dependencies looks fine, is the mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar not downloaded to you maven repository? Try to find it in $HOME/.m2/repository,